# POST variable is null when using AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to `POST` the value selected in a dropdown list using `AJAX call`. But the `POST` variable remains blank when the value is selected from the dropdown.

I have used the `ECHO method` to check whether it is returning the `POST` value. But it is empty.

Here is the code for reference:

### Javascript (Jquery and Ajax):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#booking_date").change(function(){ //listen when the option change   
        var optionValue = $("#booking_date").val();  //get the new value

        $.ajax({
            url: "doctordetails.php", //php file which recive the new value and save it to the database
            data: { optionValue: optionValue },  //send the new value
            type: "POST"  ,                  //use POST method
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(optionValue);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="booking_date" name="booking_date" data-lang="en" data-min-year="2017" data-max-year="2020" data-disabled-days="10/17/2017,11/18/2017">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select slot</option>>
        <?php
            require_once("dblogin.php");
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_POST[" optionValue "]; ?>">
          <?php echo $_POST["optionValue"]; ?>
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Expected result:

`$_POST` should return the selected value from booking_date and the `$_POST` value will be used in a SQL Query.

Comment: `try onkeyup` function https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Tried but not working.

Comment: try this $("#booking_date").on("change paste keyup", function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});

Comment: @user3616545: There is an alert with the selected value from dropdown but $POST["optionvalue"] remain blank.

Comment: Could you show your processing? also, where are you viewing the output?

Comment: After ajax success what  response you are getting? means success: function(data) {
                console.log(optionValue);
            } what is the value of data

Comment: try this $("#booking_date").on("change", function() {
var optionValue = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
            url: "doctordetails.php", 
            data: { optionValue: optionValue },  
            type: "POST"  ,                 
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(optionValue);
            }
        });

});

Comment: @ShivendraSingh: If I do console.log(data); I get the full html code with an error. With console.log(optionValue); I get the date selected from dropdown in my console.

Comment: If I do console.log(data); I get the full html code with an error. That you have need to check maybe some issue in file where you are sending the ajax request.

Comment: I think on based on date change you want to display the slot in select option. that you will get in ajax response. I'm right?

Comment: @user3616545: Result is same like before. $_POST["OptionValue"] remains blank.

Comment: @ShivendraSingh: Spot on! You are right. I want to use the POST value in a MYQL query to get time slots.

Comment: check the file where you are sending the ajax. data you will get after success the ajax that you have need to append in select option. success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }.  just check why you are getting error within that file.

Comment: You have also need to send the response in json format. after that you can append like- success: function(data) {
                //console.log(optionValue);
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {   
      $('#optionValue').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value)); 
    });
            }  . #optionValue will be id of select box

Comment: @ShivendraSingh: This is the error is get when is use console.log(data) <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in <b>/home/findadoc/public_html/doctordetails.php</b> on line <b>251</b><br />

Comment: yes, because in doctordetails.php maybe some issue in code. that you have need to check. And after fixed the code need to display the response in json format.

Comment: add the doctordetails.php file code in question, will see. maybe some issue in select query result.

Answer (score 0):

If this is dropdown list, then id must be on select box. You set id `booking_date` on textbox other than select box. write as:

`<select id="booking_date" class="form-control">
 </select>`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But your approach is not clear to me. How setting the ID for the select box will allow the $_POST variable not to be null. I tried your solution and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to value from select(dropdown) so you have to set id on `<select>` rather than textbox `<input>`

```
   <select id="booking_date" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Select slot</option>>
      <?php require_once("dblogin.php"); ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $_POST["optionValue"]; ?>">
            <?php echo $_POST["optionValue"]; ?>
      </option>

   </select>
```

On Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#booking_date").change(function(){ //listen when the option change   
        var optionValue = $(this).val();  //get the new value

        $.ajax({
            url: "doctordetails.php", //php file which recive the new value and save it to the database
            data: { getValue: optionValue },  //send the new value
            type: "POST"  ,                  //use POST method
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But your approach is not clear to me. How setting the ID for the select box will allow the $_POST variable not to be null. I tried your solution and it does not work.

Comment: would you please share code of `doctordetails.php` and try again without ajax just `$("#booking_date").change(function(){ 
        var optionValue = $(this).val(); 
        console.log(optionValue );
`

Comment: @user2122925 you may check this for the better understanding [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NQPXLR?editors=1111)

Comment: The value display correctly in the console. No issue on that part. But passing the selected in POST variable is the challenge. It remains empty.

Comment: change this `data: { optionValue: optionValue }` to this `data: { getValue: optionValue }` and on the PHP file `$_POST['getValue']` and also change `success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }`

Comment: It is a big file. What would be the easier way to share the code without it looks to messy and bulky?

Comment: You may do to overcome this problem is to make a new file and only get the posted value and echo it like in PHP file `$getVal = $_POST['getValue'];  echo $getVal;`

Comment: @user2122925 is that `doctordetails.php` ?

Comment: Yes it the doctordetails.php file

Comment: It will return null as you haven't get the POSTED value. What you are trying to do is that whatever you enter in `textbox` it will return on your `select(dropdown)` right ? As your question was very different and now I'm understanding this so correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The idea is to get the POST value and pass it in a SQL Query to get time slots from database. For now I am trying to display the POST value in the dropdown to see if the value is passed successfully. Let me know if my problem make sense now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196706/discussion-between-kamran-kb-and-user2122925).